# Python Bokeh JSCallback, filtering line graph based on Select

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I am having some trouble with writing the code in the JSCallback function in Python Bokeh.

Specifically, I am trying to create a line graph that will show only the data that is stated in the dropdown box. I have to use the JSCallback function as server-app options are disabled at work.

For example, if I have a dataset with for different series (A, B, C, D). I would like to make it so that selecting "A" in a select box will show only that series in a line graph, "B" to show B etc.  It is the equivalent of me filtering the dataset (for example, using a loc function in Pandas) before graphing the data.  I have tried my best to extrapolate from the the documentation but to not avail.  Here is a sample script.  I know the "var z == f" is incorrect, but I don't know how to filter a datatable in the JS Callback code.  Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import figure


df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"A": [1,2,3,4,5],
                          "B": [6,7,8,9,10],
                          "C": [11,12,13,14,15],
                          "D": [16,17,18,19,20],
                          "day":[100,101,102,103,104]})

df = df.melt(id_vars = ["day"], var_name = "var",  value_name = "val")
source = ColumnDataSource(dict (val = df["val"],
                                day = df["day"]))


dropdown = Select(title ="Variable", value = "A", options = ["A","B","C","D"])



p = figure(plot_height = 300, plot_width = 800)                 
p.line("day", "val", source= source)


callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source=  source), code = """

data = source.data;
var f = cb.obj_value
var z = data["variable"]
var z == f

source.change.emit()


""")


dropdown.js_on_change("value", callback)

combined= column(p, widgetbox(dropdown))

show(combined)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transform or filter something, don't change data sources. There are views, filters, and transforms in Bokeh for that.

But since you're using the line glyph, using a filter will issue a warning because line is a connected glyph. What you can do is to avoid melting the dataframe and just switch the column:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        "B": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                        "C": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                        "D": [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                        "day": [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]})

source = ColumnDataSource({c: v.values for c, v in df.items()})

initial_value = "A"
dropdown = Select(title="Variable", value=initial_value, options=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800)
l = p.line("day", initial_value, source=source)

dropdown.js_on_change("value", CustomJS(args=dict(line=l),
                                        code="line.glyph.y = {field: cb_obj.value};"))

show(column(p, dropdown))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been tearing my hair out trying to figure out the answer. Cheers.